# Android service ClassCastException when casting to custom application

Tags: android, crash, classcastexception, dagger-2, dagger

I've noticed in Google Play Console crashes that I get ClassCastException when casting to a CustomApplication in a Service or BroadcastReceiver:

```
((CustomApplication) getApplication()).getDiComponent().inject(this);
```

The name is set in manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".CustomApplication"
```

I also tried using getApplicationContext() but got same result:

```
((CustomApplication) getApplicationContext()).getDiComponent().inject(this);
```

This code is used in onCreate() method of a Service or onReceive of a broadcast receiver.
I cannot reproduce this crash but I have quite a lot looking at numbers. Any idea why it happens and how I could fix it?

UPDATES

- OS affected: from 6.0 and up
- Devices: mostly ZTE phones, 70%, but some Samsung also

Comment: I've received bunch of this kind of crashes after switching to MultiDexApplication. Do you use MultiDexApplication? I don't know what is the workaround for this issue(

Comment: Indeed. Multidex is enabled

Comment: Seems to be there is no connection with MultiDexApplication. Here is the bug I've found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137009